# What is the java code to repackage by modifying the apk's smali code?

Tags: java, android, slice, smali, software-packaging

I'm trying to make a tool in java code that automatically triggers all events in android market app.

To do this, after decompiling the apk file, I try to slice all the events and add them to one main method.

But I don't know how to repackage the sliced ​​code back into an apk.

Is it possible to repackage smali code in java?

The smali code slice will be stored as a string type, and the slice set will be stored as a list type.

However, this storage type can be changed.

Comment: `apktool` is an Java based open source tool so that would be a good starting point. But repackaging does not work on all apps. IMHO you should better use [Frida](https://frida.re). On a rooted phone you can execute, inject and modify code at run-time without the need to modify the APK.